# Пауза между скриптами Js

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

есть 3 скрипта асинхронных, и каждый ждет другого, но выполняется он 1 минуту,  и потом ничего не происходит, что и как поправить.Я использую функцию util.promisify.Как убрать это паузу, чтобы по готовности сразу к след. переходил?

```
const addOrdersToGoogleSheets = async statuses => {
  console.log("addOrdersToGoogleSheets", statuses) 
};

await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets)([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets)(12);
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода в вопросе.

Comment: Покажите код-то, иначе совершенно не понятно, например, зачем (да и как тоже) у Вас там сделана задержка в 30 минут. Без кода, все что можно посоветовать - убрать эту задержку.

Comment: Так Вы определитесь, у Вас `await` или `.then`? Ну, а так, проблема, очевидно, внутри функций.

Comment: Так [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) же требует, чтобы промисифицируемая функция имела определенную сигнатуру, в частности, последним параметром должен быть коллбэк. В показанном коде это не выполняется.